# Converting an RGB LUT to YUV and then use it to colour correct a UYVY frame?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

I have an RGB colour space LUT(33x33x33x3) with me which I convert to YUV(or UYV for simplicity of use) after trilinear interpolation(so I basically have a 256x256x256x3 LUT). Then I have a video stream in UYVY from which I am taking the frames and colour correcting using the LUT one by one. The problem is that I am getting weird colours.

My LUT file has its values in float.

My RGB LUT to UYV LUT function:

```
// input is a 256x256x256x3 RGB interpolated LUT containing values from 0-255
__global__ void cudargblut2yuv(uint8_t *input, uint8_t *output) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int idy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int idz = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;
    if (idx < 256 && idy < 256 && idz < 256) {
        int index = idx * 256 * 256 * 3 + idy * 256 * 3 + idz * 3;
        float red = input[index];
        float green = input[index + 1];
        float blue = input[index + 2];
        float y = 16 + 0.256 * red + 0.504 * green + 0.0979 * blue;
        float u = 128 + 0.439 * red - 0.368 * green - 0.0714 * blue;
        float v = 128 - 0.148 * red  - 0.291 * green + 0.439 * blue;
        
        // clamping 0-255
        if(y > 255) y = 255;
        else if(y < 0) y = 0;
        if(u < 0) u = 0;
        else if(u > 255) u = 255;
        if(v < 0) v = 0;
        else if(v > 255) v = 255;
        
        output[index] = u;
        output[index + 1] = y;
        output[index + 2] = v;
    }
}
```

My function which applies LUT to a pixel:

```
__global__
void applyLUTKernel(const uint8_t* input, uint8_t* output, int frameSize, const uint8_t* lut) {
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
    frameSize >>= 1;
    for(int i = index; i < frameSize; i += stride) {
        // UYV values from UYVY frame
        uint8_t U = input[(i << 2)];
        uint8_t Y1 = input[(i << 2) + 1];
        uint8_t V = input[(i << 2) + 2];
        uint8_t Y2 = input[(i << 2) + 3];

        uint8_t pixel1U = lut[256 * 256 * 3 * U + 256 * 3 * Y1 + 3 * V];
        uint8_t pixel1Y = lut[256 * 256 * 3 * U + 256 * 3 * Y1 + 3 * V + 1];
        uint8_t pixel1V = lut[256 * 256 * 3 * U + 256 * 3 * Y1 + 3 * V + 2];

        uint8_t pixel2U = lut[256 * 256 * 3 * U + 256 * 3 * Y2 + 3 * V];
        uint8_t pixel2Y = lut[256 * 256 * 3 * U + 256 * 3 * Y2 + 3 * V + 1];
        uint8_t pixel2V = lut[256 * 256 * 3 * U + 256 * 3 * Y2 + 3 * V + 2];

        // getting corresponding LUT[U1][Y1][V1] values to put back into the frame
        output[(i << 2)] = (pixel1U + pixel2U) >> 1;
        output[(i << 2) + 1] = pixel1Y; 
        output[(i << 2) + 2] = (pixel1V + pixel2V) >> 1;
        output[(i << 2) + 3] = pixel2Y;

        // normal frame
        // output[(i << 2)] = U;
        // output[(i << 2) + 1] = Y1;
        // output[(i << 2) + 2] = V;
        // output[(i << 2) + 3] = Y2;
    }
}
```

Could someone please correct me where I might be wrong?

I suspect that I might be converting LUT incorrectly to UYV or I am substituting the resultant LUT values back to the frame incorrectly. I feel my interpolation is accurate since before I was converting the UYVY LUT to RGB and then applying LUT, which worked perfectly as I was expecting.

I am taking the average of U1 and U2 values because logically the neighbouring pixels should not have huge difference in their values so taking their average makes sense.

What my frames look like:

[Original frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVCfG.jpg)

[LUT corrected incorrect frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvr22.jpg)

[Expected LUT corrected frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPkhX.jpg)

Comment: LUT is not a colour space. It is a transformation function (LUT or 3DLUT3), So you are just looking to build a 3dLUT which transform a RGB to a YUV, right?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi no I have an LUT which can do certain colour transformations on an RGB frame but I want this LUT to take YUV values instead as an input and produce the same results so that I can apply it to my frame which is in UYVY format. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @ShikhinDahikar Nice idea (applying LUT whilst the pixels are in YUV space), might be useful for real-time video editing (at bytes level, if a video keyframe holds YUV data).This idea cannot work that way (RGB->YUV), as you tried and seen it for yourself. The nearest approximation would be to use the **Blue** (or **Z**) to adjust the Y-channel in YUV since those 2 things serve the same purpose (they are for selecting [the tile with the required Lightness level](https://cdn.streamshark.io/obs-guide/img/neutral-lut.png), which holds the then used RGB or UV colors respectively).

Comment: @VC.One yes I am trying to apply colour correction for a livestream/broadcast/live feed only. My coworker recently gave me an idea that the index which I am using to put back the YUV values in the output whilst converting RGB->YUV LUT might be incorrect because YUV might not be like arranged similarly in a 3D space so I tried creating an RGB->YUV LUT for all possible values to fix the indices. That is also not working as expected though.
Could you please explain me why my LUT colour space conversions wont work?

Comment: @ShikhinDahikar **PS:** Although not impossible to apply a 3D LUT in YUV space it might be better to just transform the YUV to RGB, do the LUT color transform, then finally convert back into YUV. **(1)** Think about the X/Y colour gradients in an [RGB plane](https://here.isnew.info/color-models/u-rgb_color_plane_B=0.png) vs a [YUV plane](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/YUV_plane_0p5.png). The X/Y coordinates are taken from the R+G (in RGB gradient / plane), so first you are not landng on correct colour's coordinates when checking same point now within the YUV gradient.

Comment: @ShikhinDahikar OK you were typing at the same time as I was double-checking things... **(1)** The LUT colour conversions are not working because the X/Y coords you would get from the R/G channels do not land on same matching colours on the YUV side (at any same X/Y point, but now called as U/V just because x/y is suddenly boring or something...). **(2)** Also after changing the RGB table into YUV values... man, it just doesn't work like that! In U/V think of it as `U` is a left-right ratio going from Red to Green, and `V` does same ratio for Blue to Yellow. U/V just recreates the colour wheel

Comment: @ShikhinDahikar  ...U/V just recreates the colour wheel, so how is the X/Y coords from `[R/G, B]` going to translate into `[U/V, Y]`??? When converting, you are breaking down 3 R/G/B numbers into 2 points on colour wheel to get a final equivalent (to RGB) colour as U/V coords. Just trust me, LUT does not fit into the design of the YUV colour model. **(3)** It is not impossible because: **technically, those colour spaces hold the same information** just in two different ways. You have to find the equivalent transform according to YUV rules. There is no **256** in a YUV for a LUT table.

Comment: @ShikhinDahikar **to finalize**... **(1)** Consider a temporary conversion from YUV into RGB and transform there, before converting back to YUV. **(2)** Your RGB to YUV conversion (`float y, u, v;`) seems to be leaning more towards YCbCr colours not YUV colours. Try multiplying with BT.601 or BT.709 coefficients on your R-G-B values and check if the LUT is now with correct colours **(3)** Share a copy (_eg:_ file link) of a testable LUT so we can test your code for same result, someone might offer you a possible solution.

Comment: the original LUT has RGB axes, so you can look up RGB values. to look up YUV values, you need to transform the entire cube to YUV. I don't mean the *values* (output), I mean the space itself (input). if you don't do that, you'll have to transform your YUV input to RGB, then run it through the LUT. if you do that, then transforming the LUT is pointless because it might as well stay RGB-to-RGB, and you can do the YUV/RGB/YUV conversions before and after lookup.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs guys. This is my updated [github](https://github.com/shikhindahikar/LUT-transformations/tree/uyvy-lut) branch where I have now tried to fix indices. Contains couple of free LUTs that I found online to test on. Example frames above use this [LUT](https://github.com/shikhindahikar/LUT-transformations/blob/uyvy-lut/Print%2BFilm%2BEmulation%2BLUTs/smallhd_movielooks/SmallHD_MovieLook_BBoyz2.cube) as of now. Previously I was doing UYVY->RGB then colour correct and RGB->UYVY as suggested by @VC.One but that adds lot of overhead that I cannot afford for 4K frames.

Comment: In the above code I get wrong colours and very noticable artifacts. Video is quite clear though.

Answer (score 1):

One problem that you have is that you are using unsigned byte types for doing arithmetic on the pixel values where an overflow is possible. During addition when you are putting the values back into the output stream the intermediate result of the sum will be computed modulo 256! The following minor changes to your code ought to improve things and prevent loss of significant data due to overflows.

```
    int32_t pixel1U = lut[256 * 256 * 3 * U + 256 * 3 * Y1 + 3 * V];
    uint8_t pixel1Y = lut[256 * 256 * 3 * U + 256 * 3 * Y1 + 3 * V + 1];
    int32_t pixel1V = lut[256 * 256 * 3 * U + 256 * 3 * Y1 + 3 * V + 2];

    int32_t pixel2U = lut[256 * 256 * 3 * U + 256 * 3 * Y2 + 3 * V];
    uint8_t pixel2Y = lut[256 * 256 * 3 * U + 256 * 3 * Y2 + 3 * V + 1];
    int32_t pixel2V = lut[256 * 256 * 3 * U + 256 * 3 * Y2 + 3 * V + 2];


 // getting corresponding LUT[U1][Y1][V1] values to put back into the frame
    output[(i << 2)]     = (uint8_t) ((pixel1U + pixel2U) >> 1);
    output[(i << 2) + 1] = pixel1Y; 
    output[(i << 2) + 2] = (uint8_t) ((pixel1V + pixel2V) >> 1);
    output[(i << 2) + 3] = pixel2Y;
```

Note that U and V components will be corrupted if the contributing values 1U + 2U, 1V + 2V sum exceeds 256 (a situation that seems to occur mostly on the green grass).

You will probably find that  your code runs faster too if you promote the working variables inside the arithmetic loop into 32 bit integers. The code would be much clearer if you computed the indexing once.

The same stylistic observation also applies to using "i<<2" as an index throughout - you might as well multiply both the stride and framesize by 4.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs but unfortunately it is still showing lot of artifacts. This question is not directly relevant to me anymore since I tried something else.

Comment: Sorry it didn't fix your problem. Worth looking carefully to see if there are any other potential overflows lurking elsewhere in the code. Arithmetic on unsigned quantities can go horribly wrong and it is hard to spot because the expression is what you intended but the code that it generates is not. I can see that there will be some gross approximations around edge cases in the LUT but was hoping a few isolated pixels wouldn't be too obtrusive. I guessed wrong. Be a neat trick if it can be made to work...

Answer (score 0):

This was not successful but instead of converting the LUT colour space I have just temporarily converted the UYVY pixel to RGB pixels then applied LUT and converted back them to UYVY pixel. This works much better than converting entire frame at once to UYVY or RGB for my use case.